# Is there any way I can make podcast application from iphone play my podcasts ? ( with code )

Tags: ios, playback, podcast

I'm doing an application that can play podcasts, but i feel more comfortable if the iPhone default podcast application plays the files, instead of me having to handle them.

When I pass the URL to the sharedApplication object, Safari opens and starts playing it ... but I'd like to skip the user seeing Safari. Is there any way?

Comment: Already saved podcasts can be played using the API accessing the default podcast application itself. But I don't think you can save anything to it like we do with photos and address book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The podcasts app does not have a public API. Therefore you cannot get it to play podcasts on your behalf.

Since the podcasts are added to your media library you should be able to find them with a media library query and start background playback easily.